# Firebase swift Cross-app user sharing not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, today-extension

I am working on adding a Today extension for my app, which will need to use FirebaseAuth, so I followed the instructions on the Firebase Documentation and set up the Keychain access group by adding it in the Signing & Capabilities tab, where I wrote it in the format: `{TEAM_ID}.com.{appOrg}.{appBundle}.{groupName}` and initialized it using the code below in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of the AppDelegate of my app, and the `viewDidLoad()` of my today extension, called after `FirebaseApp.configure()` in both instances.

Here is the code:

```
do {
   try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("{TEAM_ID}.com.{appOrg}.{appBundle}.{groupName}")
]} catch let error as NSError {
   print("Error changing user access group: \(error.code)")        
}
```

Both calls give me the same error code: 0, which also translates to `The operation couldn’t be completed.` when I use `error.localizedDescription`

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Not sure if it will make any difference, but my app is a Flutter app, though the today view and code aboce is in the swift files, called upon launch of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after several attempts under my thoughts that it was my setup of the keychain group, it ended up being that I was calling the code too early (right after configuring the FirebaseApp), so it just failed. Moving the code out of viewDidLoad and into a method called by a method channel right before login (for the app) and before I needed the user to populate the today extension worked for me.